# How do I get a spring boot bean after injecting it?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

I’m new to spring boot and trying to understand how beans work. My goal is to create a bean called `pizza` that can be accessed/used throughout my project. I used constructor-based injection to inject the bean. This is my current set-up:

```
@Configuration
public class PizzaConfiguration {

    protected final Pizza pizza;

    @Autowired
    public PizzaConfiguration(Pizza pizza) {
        this.pizza = pizza;
    }

    @Bean
    public Pizza getPizza() {
       Pizza pizza = new Pizza();
       pizza.hasCheese(true);
       pizza.addTopping(“pepperoni”);
       pizza.addTopping(“onions”);
       pizza.addTopping(“sausage”);
       return pizza;
    }
}
```

Now, in separate classes, I want to access the pizza bean such that `pizza.hasCheese()` will return true, and `pizza.getToppings()` will return `[pepperoni, onions, sausage].` I’m a bit confused because doing something like:

```
PizzaConfiguration pc = new PizzaConfiguration(new Pizza())
```

won’t actually inject the bean. What would be the correct way to access the bean?

Comment: You normally should only inject _service_ objects rather than _data_ objects. You also seem to be confused about the lifecycle, trying to both _supply_ and _consume_ a bean in the same class. Nevertheless, the point of DI is that you should eliminate the use of `new` (except within `@Configuration @Bean` methods) and instead make your bean a constructor parameter _where you need it_.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Injection means the Spring container would help to 'injects' objects into other objects.
And when you create a object in your program, the Spring container will not perceiving that.
You can use SpringContext to access the bean or by code it in your program such as `@Resource`,`@Autowire` and so on.